# Can you find the actual amount of data downloaded in a file, which it's still downloading?

Tags: file-transfer

I'm downloading a 5.28GB `.bak` file from Azure Storage Explorer. The `Size on disk` shows as 5.28 GB (5,672,402,944 bytes) but the file isn't downloaded yet. I can't see a %'age download in Azure Storage Explorer, so I don't know how much of the file is downloaded.

Can I view how much is **actually** downloaded?

Comment: In Windows, in the Adapter Properties, you can see the number of bytes transferred. If that is all you are doing of any consequence, that would give you a very good indication. Web browsing should not greatly affect the measurement.   That is one way.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your environment correctly. I did look around a bit. Adapter Watch (Nirsoft) and DU Meter (which I have) seem to be based on the same principle as the Adapter Properties. Separately, Resource Monitor (Windows Tools) can measure received Bytes by application and that may help you.